# Qt application crashes on exit after switching compiler from gcc to msvc

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, visual-studio-2012

For recent years I've been writing a commercial app with Qt ( from 4.7 to 5.1(now)). And I've been switching between gcc and msvc compiler to test the platform and framework compatibility in casual intervals.

Now, After building the project with Qt5.1-msvc2010 and importing it into the visual studio editor(2013), The project crashes on exit.
After that, I rebuilt and debug it with qtcreator editor but the program crashed on exit again.

This window appears when the project crashes with the qtcreator editor on exit. I assure you there is no "f:\dd" path in my computer!!!
[image]

So there is nothing to do with the editors and I think this issue is related to the msvc compiler.
After debugging, it toggles in the destructor of the mainwindow, but there is just "delete ui;".

I'm pretty aware of how a QObject delete their children and I have never delete any GUI component by myself.

This issue confused me since the gcc compiler is more strict than the msvc.
I'll be appreciated for Any guidance or instruction.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It is internal Microsoft CRT (C Run-time Library) code that is generating the error, not your application's code. So the file path ("f:\dd\vctools...") refers to the path of the source file on Microsoft's servers when the debug symbols were created. You aren't going to be able to find it.

What's happening is that the debug version of the CRT contains lots of extra checks, to aid in catching bugs hiding in your programs. In this case, it's detecting an attempt to use an invalid heap pointer (by calling the internal `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` function, which is failing).

To fix the problem, you'll need to track down where your code is using the invalid pointer. You can pretty much assume that this error is caused by trying to free/delete memory that is not allocated on the heap. You say that the debugger breaks on the line `delete ui;`—make sure that `ui` is actually created on the heap somewhere with `new`, not automatically created on the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I'll check that.